# Why isn't the animateActiveItem function animating in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have the following code in my app class:

```
 switchMainView: function (newView, config) {
        if (this.currentView != false) {
            Ext.Viewport.remove(this.currentView);
        }

        this.currentView = Ext.create(newView, config);        
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(this.currentView, { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' })
    },
```

Which can be called from any controller.  However, it is not showing the animation. Any ideas what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to sencha guys :

AnimateActiveItem(activeItem,animation ) will

Animates to the supplied activeItem with a specified animation. **Currently this only works with a Card layout**. This passed animation will override any default animations on the container, for a single card switch. The animation will be destroyed when complete.

```
viewport: {
layout: {
    type: 'card'
}
```

}

add above code in app.js

Comment: yes I agree with this, with card layout you can perform animation.

Comment: I'd like to add to this, as this was partially due to lack of understanding on my part. The viewport only animates if there is something to animate from and to.  If there is only one card i.e. I remove the first then add a new one it won't work as it transitioning from 0 to 1 cards.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the "this.currentView" view isn't part of the viewport yet. Use this line before the animateActiveItem line:

```
Ext.Viewport.add(this.currentView);
```

This should make it work.

Comment: Doesn't work, I commented out the animation line and as soon as  add() is called it comes into view...